# cant resolve class in scala akka example programm

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka

hey i am new to scala and akka and i wanted to try this example programm i found in intellij. Unfortunately it does not work. I am not sure why it does not work but i am also new to intellij and i think it could be a problem with the libaries i loaded. Anyway here is code i found. This is the Printer class:

```
package test
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging}

class Printer extends Actor with ActorLogging{
  import Printer._

  def receive={
    case Greeting(greeting)=>
   log.info(s"Greeting received (from ${sender()}): $greeting")
 }
}
```

Now comes the Greeter class:

```
package test
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, ActorRef, Props}
class Greeter(message: String, printerActor: ActorRef) extends Actor with 
ActorLogging {
  import Greeter._
  import Printer._
  var greeting = ""
  def receive = {
    case WhoToGreet(who) =>
      greeting = s"$message, $who"
    case Greet =>
  printerActor ! Greeting(greeting)
  }
}
```

And now the main:

```
package test
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import scala.io.StdIn
object main extends App {
  import Greeter._
  // Create the 'helloAkka' actor system
  val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("helloAkka")
    try {
    // Create the printer actor
    val printer: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Printer.props, "printerActor")
    // Create the 'greeter' actors
    val howdyGreeter: ActorRef =
   system.actorOf(Greeter.props("Howdy", printer), "howdyGreeter")
   // Send messages
   howdyGreeter ! WhoToGreet("Akka")
   howdyGreeter ! Greet
    println(">>> Press ENTER to exit <<<")
   StdIn.readLine()
   } finally {
   system.terminate()
      }
   }
```

i got several "cannot resolve" errors. First at all, why do  i need the import statements in Printer and Greeter (import Greeter._ / Printer._) they are marked as cannot resolve. Also every Printer or Greeter is marked as cannot resolve.
here are my errors:

```
C:\Users\olive\IdeaProjects\akkat\src\test\scala\test\Greeter.scala
Error:(4, 10) not found: value Greeter
  import Greeter._
Error:(5, 10) not found: value Printer
  import Printer._
Error:(8, 10) not found: value WhoToGreet
    case WhoToGreet(who) =>
Error:(10, 10) not found: value Greet
    case Greet =>
Error:(11, 22) not found: value Greeting
      printerActor ! Greeting(greeting)
C:\Users\olive\IdeaProjects\akkat\src\test\scala\test\Printer.scala
Error:(6, 10) not found: value Printer
  import Printer._
Error:(9, 10) not found: value Greeting
    case Greeting(greeting)=>
C:\Users\olive\IdeaProjects\akkat\src\test\scala\test\main.scala
Error:(5, 10) not found: value Greeter
  import Greeter._
Error:(10, 44) not found: value Printer
     val printer: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Printer.props, "printerActor")
Error:(13, 20) not found: value Greeter
     system.actorOf(Greeter.props("Howdy", printer), "howdyGreeter")
Error:(15, 20) not found: value WhoToGreet
    howdyGreeter ! WhoToGreet("Akka")
Error:(16, 20) not found: value Greet
    howdyGreeter ! Greet
```

these are the libaries i loaded
[libaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxAVm.png)

Comment: Where is the case class for WhoToGreet and Greet?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create Companion Object related to scala class.

ex. For Printer class

```
object Printer {
   def props: Props = Props[Printer]
   final case class Greeting(greeting: String)
}
```

For Greeter :

```
object Greeter {
   def props(message: String, printerActor: ActorRef): Props = 
   Props(new Greeter(message, printerActor))
   final case class WhoToGreet(who: String)
   case object Greet
}
```

And you have to import these companion object into scala class which is a actor for use their properties

**Compainon Object are the same name as scala class**

[Companion Object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html)